# How Native JavaScript Promise Handles Blocking Code

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise

(The first obstacle when posting this was deciding on a good title - hope I did OK with that.)

I'm slightly bewildered by how the native JavaScript `Promise` object behaves (tested in Chrome and Firefox in Windows 7), and whether or not they actually execute in parallel or not. I sought enlightenment here on SO, but found none as of yet.

Consider this block of code:

```
(function PromiseTester() {
    var counter = 0;
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            counter = i;

        resolve();
    }).then(function() {console.log('a: ' + counter)});

    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve();
    }).then(function() {console.log('b: ' + counter)});

    console.log('When is this?');
})();
```

How can I explain the following output to the console?

> When is this?
>   a: 499999999
>   b: 499999999

It would seem that although creating the Promises is not a blocking operation in itself, the blocking loop in the first one effectively hinders the second one from resolving first.

I also tried putting the `Promise`objects in an array and test them with `Promise.race()`. It seems that code in the `then()` method of the `race()` `Promise` does not execute until the loop in the first `Promise` is finished.

Maybe this is all sober and dandy, but I don't quite get what to make of it all. Shouldn't the `Promise` objects execute and resolve in parallel?

I'd be much obliged for any attempts to clarify the situation, and how to use `Promise` properly for parallel execution.

(Please not that this question is not about `Promise.resolve()`, `Promise.all()` etc. but about the parallel - or possibly not parallel - nature of a JavaScript `Promise`.)

---

**EDIT:** In some of my comments, I said I have the same issue as described above even when replacing the loop with something asynchronous. This was wrong, and just to avoid any ambiguity, here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Promise Tester</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Check the console!</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function Main() {
                var urls = [
                    'Pages/SlowPage.aspx',
                    'Pages/Page1.html',
                    'Pages/SlowerPage.aspx',
                    'Pages/Page2.html'
                ];

                var promises = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

                    (function AddPromise(url) {
                        promises.push(
                            new Promise(function (resolve) {
                                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                request.onload = function () {
                                    resolve(url);
                                };
                                request.open('GET', url, true);
                                request.send();
                            })
                            .then(function (result) {
                                console.log('Resolved ' + url + '.');
                            })
                        );
                    })(urls[i])
                }

                Promise
                    .race(promises)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('First promise resolved.');
                    });

                Promise
                    .all(promises)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('All promises resolved.');
                    });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `html` pages are just that - plain and simple HTML pages, but in the `aspx` pages i put some server side `Thread.Sleep()` code to make them "slow". While perhaps not one-hundred-percent-absolutely-bulletproof, it should provide a sufficient solution for testing in this context, and the output to the console is as follows:

> Resolved Pages/Page1.html.
>   Resolved Pages/Page2.html.
>   First promise resolved.
>   Resolved Pages/SlowPage.aspx.
>   Resolved Pages/SlowerPage.aspx.
>   All promises resolved.

In my original question, I thought it was confusing that the phrase "When is this?" was logged *before* any of the `Promise` objects resolved. Likewise, I think it's somewhat unexpected that the `html` pages consistently (always?) resolves before `Promise.race` realizes that at least one `Promise` was resolved. If anyone would care to further elaborate on that I'd be interested to hear, but if not I'm satisfied with the conclusion that "that's just how it is", for now.

**EDIT:** I really mean "concurrent" rather than "parallel" in all of the above.

Comment: JavaScript is executed sequentially and synchronously. There are no asynchronous operations in your code. I don't know why you would expect a different result.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded (unless you use webworkers etc).  Your posted code will run in the order requested, since there's no asynchronous work in your promises, they will log in order called.

Comment: If instead of a loop I make an asynchronous AJAX request, the issue remains the same though.

Comment: @OskarLindberg Did you call `resolve()` on completion of the AJAX request, or just after you've fired it - ie did you move the call to `resolve` into a success callback or similar, or did the AJAX request directly replace the `for` loop in your question, with the call to `resolve` still sitting after it?

Comment: I resolved on completion. Shouldn't I? It seemed such a good idea to get to work on the response and the resolve the modified result.

Comment: In normal Ajax operations you return the result of the asynchronous request through the `resolve()` and handle it in your `then()` callback. Your test isn't a true asynchronous operation because of the `for` loop. Instead, use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Brett I know that my test is not asynchronous - I wanted it to be blocking because I didn't "get it". As you can see from my response to other comments, when I did exactly what you describe with "true" asynchronous code, I still seemed to have the same issue. I gather that I must have been mistaken? If asynchronous request "b" is completed before request "a", then the second `Promise().then()` should execute first?

Comment: @OskarLindberg It's not clear what you mean by "on completion" - perhaps you could edit your question to include your async example too

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I might. As I was telling Mr Renauld below, it seems my mistake was primarily to assume that `Promise` would be something more than "semantics" - and maybe it still is - I just meant useful for parallelism (being natively supported and all nowadays). The second part of my confusion was about not getting the results I wanted with asynchronous requests either, but I gather that must be out of some mistake entirely on my part. If indeed I find that I cannot solve this latter issue by refining my debugging, I will be back. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the confusion between an event loop and multithreading...

When you instantiate your first promise, the underlying implementation is such that after the creation, JavaScript hands over control back to the next instruction, which is to start the loop. This instruction (if you prefer, the `function` IETF in the promise) starts running, and **does not stop** until the loop has run its full course. At no point is there a way for the event loop to notice that your loop is "partially done" but that it's okay to go and slot in a couple of operations until the next iteration.

When the loop is over, the promise is marked as completed, and the event loop decides to pick the next in order - your second promise!

If you'd like to do it another way without invoking webworkers or switching language, at a huge cost of performance, you could `process.nextTick()` (or, since you're in a browser, `setTimeout(function() {}, 0)`) every iteration of your loop in order to see that what I'm saying is correct. You will then see promise #2 being completed due to every iteration of the loop being "handed back" to the event loop.

In reality, where you are expecting JS to be multithreaded, it is just event-driven. Difference in conception with huge implications.

Comment: Yes JavaScript is single-threaded (unless setTimeout and all that), but I don't get the purpose of e.g. `Promise.race()` if I still have to wait for one "heavy" `Promise` to finish before being allowed to get to work on a second one that's "lighter". Isn't that sort of serializing execution in the order of declaration..?

Comment: @OskarLindberg "unless setTimeout" - using timeouts is still single threaded.  If you set a timeout for 2 seconds and another for 3 seconds, if the first one takes 5 seconds to run, the second one won't happen until 7 seconds have elapsed, not 3.  There is no parallel execution in javascript, ever (webworkers aside).  `Promise.race` is for when asynchronous code is run - eg ajax calls to a server, the first one to return will "win" - you can't get around blocking code in javascript - it will always block everything, including the UI (unless a webworker).

Comment: @OskarLindberg: First off, `setTimeout` does not do anything regarding single-threadedness. It just hands back control of execution to something else. `Promise.race` does not do that, either. Your issue is "running something heavy, sequential and without giving control back at any point", **not** the method of doing it, and `Promises` do not help on that front. Promises are designed for purely async, non-blocking tasks (XHR calls are the best and brightest in that category).

Comment: Yes I know. I was being careless with my statement - thanks for correcting it. I was merely referring to the fact that you can get "parallel-like behavior" with things like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, much like Mr Renauld suggests in his answer above. EDIT: Actually, Mr Renauld did not suggest any such thing - I was being careless again, and I apologize.

Comment: @OskarLindberg: If you're in a browser, consider the `WebWorker` API for your "heavy" loop and signal when it's finished (with the value :-) ) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage . The messaging (signalling, really) API is also pretty nice. If you really don't want to go into another thread, consider `setTimeout` to artificially allow execution of other statements while running through your loop, though it remains a very dirty and very inefficient hack.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your patience. I guess I'm mostly confused by the actual reality that - as you say - `Promise` does not help in and of itself with parallelism. I sort of got the impression that it would.

Comment: @OskarLindberg: It **can** help, but it is important to note that it is not a panacea, as you've just discovered :-)

Comment: A final note on my being careless - I really should have been talking about "concurrency" rather than "parallelism" to begin with.