# Using Promises to make In Memory Processing Concurrent

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

We have a project where we need to process ~5,000 objects and each object takes 200-500 milliseconds each to process. A developer on my team suggested using promises to try to process each object concurrently.  So basically something like this:

```
let result = await Promise.all(objects.map(o => process(o));
```

The `process()` code might look like this:

```
async process(theObject) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    1 + 1 = 2;
    resolve();
  });
}
```

While it seems like a fair pattern, it seems like an anti-pattern, or a code smell. There also seems to be something about how Node/V8 handles promises that might introduce major issues later. Anyone have any thoughts on this pattern and whether it might be use-ful/less?

Comment: There are 2 things wich micght be a problem. 1) Promise.all waits for ALL promises to finish before it continues and 2) if one promise is rejected without being cought the Promise.all is also rejected.

Comment: "*might look like this*" - please show your actual code. Promises are only of use when your processing is asynchronous. [Promises don't make anything concurrent by themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

One caveat of using `Promise.all()` is how it handles errors. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

So if a single processing error of the ~5000 objects stops the entire process is okay, then it seems like a decent tool. I would recommend setting up a queue to both separate out the processing from the orchestration of the messages as well as provide scalability advantages.

Comment: Rejecting a promise doesn't stop the entire process, all it does is to call the error handler immediately. All the unfinished asynchronous tasks will keep running, until you explicitly stop them (if they can be stopped at all).