# Execution of asynchronous code like Promises under the hood

Tags: javascript, node.js

How does Node.js (and JavaScript in general) implement the execution of asynchronous code like Promises under the hood? Does it run a new thread? Does it use Worker for that or there is some OS or libuv functionality?

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    let now = new Date(); 
    while((now - 6000) < start){
        now = new Date();
    }
    resolve(now - start)
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    let now = new Date(); 
    while((now - 6000) < start){
        now = new Date();
    }
    resolve(now - start)
});
let start = new Date(); 
promise1.then(
    function(value) {
      console.log("Promise 1: ", value);
    }
)

promise2.then(
    function(value) {
      let finish = new Date();
      console.log("Promise 2: ", value);
      console.log(finish - start);
    }
)
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick
They use event loops

Comment: [Read all about it](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) - in short - JavaScript is a synchronous, run-to-completion, single-threaded runtime. So no new threads for the purposes of async behavior. Only when a new task (or microtask) gets put onto the stack can it execute. Asynch tasks get put onto the stack at some time in the future.

Comment: @ParvSharma yeah, I know. I understood that asynchronous operation with the filesystem libuv makes in a separate thread,  http operation runs by using OS asynchronous functions. But what happens when Promises are run? Or when we wrap code in async/await?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, ok. But when we put the new async task in the future, who will perform it? If all 'heavy' code will be performed in EventLoop, it will block it with every 'heavy' call. Instead of that EventLoop run is asynchronously (somehow) and execute only the result's callback. So I'm trying to understand where this async code execute?  =)

Comment: @ParvSharma - has provided the answer. The async tasks are queued (on the heap), waiting for the stack to clear. Once the stack clears the queue is placed on to the stack and those tasks are run to completion. There is no contention between threads, so technically there can be no "blocking". There is a delay in when the queued tasks get placed onto the stack - that "feels" like blocking while it isn't really. It simply waiting for the single thread.

Comment: @DmytroHuz Promises don't "run", they're just objects representing a result. The actually asynchronous stuff like timeout, network requests, io and such is started by a specific function that has nothing to do with promises, and how the async task is executed (libuv, threads, something else) depends on what the specific task is. And async/await code is just like normal `then` callbacks, it runs in the same main loop as all other js code.

Comment: Guys, thanks for comments. But I still have doubts. please, take a look, I added code to the question. If Node.js would be really not async the result will be 6000 and 12000.  But it is 6000 and 6000, so these functions performed simultaneously. Or I do not understand something?

Comment: Your Promise constructor callbacks run one at a time in series. The constructor callback is called synchronously and it unconditionally resolves synchronously inside it. I.E. they are not doing anything asynchronous. The first function runs for 6 seconds and resolves with the value 6000, then after the first one has resolved, the second one starts and doesn't need to loop at all because six seconds has already passed since `start` was assigned a value. If you reset start before creating the second Promise your code would take twelve seconds to run, not six (but both will still output 6000).

Comment: No, [the promise executor function is run synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js). Promises don't make anything run in parallel. And you shouldn't use them for synchronous (busy-waiting) code at all - if you were to use `setTimeout` for the 6 second timeouts, then the two `setTimeout`s *would* happen concurrently.

Comment: @Paulpro god damn, you are totally right. I changed a code And it really works synchronously. Many thanks that shown me that. And thanks all of you! Now it is clear for me. But we still can use Workers to run the really async code, right?

Comment: @DmytroHuz Yes, you can use Workers to run code in parallel on multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are not asynchronous in Node.js. But there is a new feature - Worker that is asynchronous. It runs in a separate proccess. So you can use that, here is a bit more info: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html