# Execute method in parallel using async/await

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, async-await

I am working on building multiple languages when running a gradle command for an angular application.

Below is the code which is used to build all the localized files.

The `buildAllLanguageVersion()` method is called to build the language one by one by iterating over all the available build languages.

```
   function buildAllLanguageVersion() {
    return new Promise(async (accept, reject) => {
        const doneLanguages = [];
        const applicationBase = "APPNAME";
        for (let language of buildLanguages) {
         
            const ret = await buildingLanguage(language);
            doneLanguages.push(ret);
        }
        accept(doneLanguages);
    });
}

        
        
    function buildingLanguage(buildLanguage) {
        return new Promise(accept => {
            console.log("Language building" + buildLanguage);
            const languagePath = path.resolve(`./src/i18n/messages.${buildLanguage}.xlf`);
            const languageFile = fs.existsSync(languagePath) ? buildLanguage : "en";
            if (languageFile !== buildLanguage && !fs.existsSync(languagePath)) {
                console.error(
                    "Language file does not exist." +
                        buildLanguage
                );
            }
           exec.exec(`${folder} build --configuration=dynamic`, (error, stdout, stderror) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw "Build failed: " + error;
                }
                accept(buildLanguage);
            });
        });
    }
```

The above code is working fine when I have to build a language in a sequential order. And for a language to build it took almost 3-5 minutes. I am using 7 different languages for now in the application.

My question is how I can call the method in parallel so that I can reduce the build time.

So far i have tried `Promise.all()` in the method `buildAllLanguageVersion()` to call the method `buildingLanguage()` in parallel, but that didn't help. The methods are getting called at a time(in parallel) but the build is getting failed with below error.

```
14:31:17 D:\ls\workspace\Generic_commit\APP\app-name\tools\build-all.js:129
14:31:17 throw "Build failed: " + error;
14:31:17 ^
14:31:17 Build failed: Error: Command failed: D:\ls\workspace\Generic_commit\APP\app-name\node_modules\.bin\ng.cmd build --configuration=dynamic
14:31:17
14:31:17 ERROR in ngcc is already running at process with id 5252.
14:31:17 If you are running multiple builds in parallel then you should pre-process your node_modules via the command line ngcc tool before starting the builds;
14:31:17 See https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#speeding-up-ngcc-compilation.
14:31:17 (If you are sure no ngcc process is running then you should delete the lock-file at D:/ls/workspace/Generic_commit/APP/app-name/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/_ngcc_lock_file_.)
```

I tried removing the `_ngcc_lock_file_` but that didn't help.

Comment: `return new Promise(async accept` is an anti-pattern - never make the executor of a `new Promise` async - if you do, you know you're using promises wrong

Comment: There is no parallel execution in JavaScript. All you can do is create multiple concurrent tasks at once, then combine their promises using `Promise.all` to wait for all of them.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js). What you should do in your code is make the `writeFileSync` a proper async call, and put a `new Promise` around the `exec.exec` part only. The rest of your code appears to be synchronous processing.

Comment: @Bergi : I have tried with creating multiple concurrent task at once and then combined in `Promise.all` but after that also I was getting the same error as i mentioned above.

Comment: @User_Alpha So your question is not about `async`/`await` syntax, but about how to use the `ngcc`?

Comment: @Bergi My question is to execute and build the languages in parallel so that the overall build time can be reduced. The above mentioned code is working for a sequential build.