# How to write async function to find string enumerations in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I did a function to find string enumerations but i didn `t succeed to repeat it in a async way, i'm not getting any result:

```
const stringEnumerationsAsync = async (str) => {
    let strChars = str.split("");
    let enumerations = new Set();

    const getEnumerations = (chars, enumertion) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (chars.length === 0) {
                resolve(enumertion);
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                    let newChars = [...chars];
                    let char = newChars.splice(i, 1);
                    let newEnumeration = enumertion + char;
                    getEnumerations(newChars, newEnumeration).then((finalEnumeration) => {
                        enumerations.add(finalEnumeration);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };

    await getEnumerations(strChars, "");

    return [...enumerations];
};
```

Comment: You don't await a promise, should be  **promise.then(successCallback, failureCallback);**

Comment: @NikkoLaurenciana You can actually "await" a promise, it's just syntactic sugar for the 'then' statement along with some other useful features:
https://repl.it/@SagiLevi1/PoorBouncyParser?lite=true#index.js

Comment: What's the point of using `async` here? Nothing about that function is asynchronous. You should just use the synchronous version that works.

Comment: Please clarify what your goal is, but I suspect this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

- with `getEnumerations(newChars, newEnumeration).then((finalEnumeration)...` you seem to expect *one* enumeration from the recursive call, but you should expect one or more enumerations.
- In fact, you are mixing up two patterns: one where you collect the result from (resolved) return values, and one where you collect them in a non-local variable. So if you go for the latter, you should not expect anything useful from the resolved value you get from the recursive call. Instead add enumerations to the non-local variable in the base case, and only there.
- In the `else` block you don't call `resolve`, meaning that the `new Promise` never gets resolved.
- You should actually not need to create a `new Promise` in the `else` case, as you will get promises from the recursive calls, and it is an anti-pattern to wrap that inside a promise constructor call back. So the `if...else` should be moved outside of `new Promise`
- And then in the `if` case you would get an immediately resolving promise, because you call `resolve` immediately. In that case you might as well call `Promise.resolve` instead of `new Promise`.
- Even more simple is to make `getEnumerations` an `async` function so that you only need to *return* the resolution value, and since we don't care about the resolution value,... well, we just need to return ;-)

So that brings us to this code:

```js
const stringEnumerationsAsync = async (str) => {
    let strChars = str.split("");
    let enumerations = new Set();

    const getEnumerations = async (chars, enumertion) => {
        if (chars.length === 0) {
            enumerations.add(enumertion);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                let newChars = [...chars];
                let char = newChars.splice(i, 1);
                let newEnumeration = enumertion + char;
                await getEnumerations(newChars, newEnumeration);
            }
        }
    };

    await getEnumerations(strChars, "");

    return [...enumerations];
};

// demo
stringEnumerationsAsync("abc").then(console.log);
console.log("this is synchronous");
```

---

Comment: But in this way the solution is not in a asynchronous way. the function is waiting to the resut and then move to next itaretion. you can write it withount the async-await.

Comment: @abj, you are mistaken. I added a synchronous output *after* the call of `stringEnumerationsAsync`. As you can see the outputs made based on the async function only happen after that. Moreover, every time `await` is executed, the function that has it, returns. And that execution context is only restored when the corresponding promisejob is processed from the promise queue.