# Use promise all() for expensive computations in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Is there any point to use promise all() to speed up an expensive computation ? For example:

// Expensive computation

```
const data = [1, 2, 3];

const f = (x) => {
  return x*x; // or a more complex formula
}
```

// No promises

```
const f_data = data.map(f);
```

// With promises

```
const f_data = Promise.all(data.map((e) => Promise((e) => f(e))).then(res => res).catch(...);
```

Will there be any actual difference in execution speed ?

Comment: Why would `Promise.all` speed up anything? The async tasks would still take the same time. Moreover, you don't seem to have async tasks. Running something as a promise doesn't actually spawn another process or equivalent.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js

Comment: "*Will there be any actual difference in execution speed?*" - yes, the promises solution will be slower since it creates a bunch of unnecessary objects. But not enough to matter if the computation is actually expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to speed up computations you have to use [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in order to leverage multithreading.

If you use `Promise.all`, all of the callbacks will be queued and will run in a single thread, one after the other.