# Run node.js functions in parallel

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am new to Node.js and I wanted some functions to run simultaneously.
I have seen several articles and as far as I understood I can use `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled`.
I don't understand why my functions run sequentially, here's the code I arranged.

```
async processPropositions(proposition) {
        const dataWords = [];
        const start = Date.now()

        //async functions that return promises
        const invariableData = this.invariables(propositionSplitted);
        const nounsData = this.nouns(propositionSplitted);
        const adjectivesData = this.adjectives(propositionSplitted);
        const verbsData = this.verbs(propositionSplitted);

        //here the code should stop until every promise is resolved
        const [invariables, nouns, adjectives, verbs] = await Promise.all([invariableData, nounsData, adjectivesData, verbsData]);

        //I find this time == to the sum of the time printed in the single functions abo
        const finish = Date.now()
        const time = finish - start
        console.log(time)

        //here in the original function I append results to dataWords
        
        return dataWords;
    }
```

I have printed the time of the single async functions (i.e. `this.invariables(propositionSplitted);`, `this.nouns(propositionSplitted);`, `this.adjectives(propositionSplitted);`, `this.verbs(propositionSplitted);`) and their sum is equal to the `time` I'm printing with this function.

I have the same problem when I try to run the main function for every `proposition` of the array `propositions` with a for loop. Since they're indipendent I'd like to run them simultaneously and then collecting results when every promise is solved.
I tried this but obviously I'm missing a fundamental concept of asynchronous coding:

```
        for (let proposition of propositions) {
        results.push(this.processPropositions(proposition));
        for (let result of results) {
            dataWords.push(await result);
            if (propositions.length > 1 && results.indexOf(result) < conjunctions.length) dataWords.push(Conjunctions.getConjunction(conjunctions[results.indexOf(result)]));
        }
    }
```

If I don't `await` the for loop finishes before it receives the premise, while if I keep the `await` it becomes synchronous.

Comment: so the time checks you're seeking need to be after you've got all the promises returned.  Right now you can execute that time check before the promises complete.  They don't block execution, but leveraging the resolution of the promise will yield you the true time spent.

Comment: I don't think I got what you said, but I have another time check at the end of the whole process (the function of the second snippet) and it is too high (few milliseconds different from the check in `processProposition()`: the code is executed synchronously.

Comment: What is `this.processPropositions` doing? Is it even doing anything asynchronous?

Comment: [Promises don't make anything asynchronous or in "run things in parallel", they're a tool to make working with things that already *are* asynchronous easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js).

Comment: @Bergi thanks.
`processPropositions` is simply calling different smaller indipendent functions and collecting the results from them. Since they are indipendent I'd like them to run simultaneously, in order to improve performance.
In the link I can read that "Run it in a separate child process and get an asynchronous notification when it's done.", and I think this is actually what's happening in `processProposition`: as you can see in the first block of code I am calling several functions declared with the `async` keyword, so they should be asynchronous, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Doombringer No. Being declared as `async` only means that they return a promise and can use `await` internally. It does not mean they're run in a separate process - for that you need [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop isn't waiting for the promises to resolve. Load up all the promises like you are doing in the outer loop, but don't check for resolutions until after they are fulfilled. Then you can loop through the results.

```js
function myPromise(duration) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(duration);
        }, duration);
    });
}

const propositions = [ 200, 500, 4000 ];
const promises = [];
for(const proposition of propositions) {
    promises.push(myPromise(proposition));
}
const start = Date.now();
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    const totalTime = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(`all timers finished in ${totalTime}`);
    results.forEach((t, i) => {
        console.log(`  timer ${i} took ${t}`);
    });
});
```