# how to apply javascript promises for async data hashing

Tags: javascript, hash, blockchain, es6-promise

In an online blockchain developer course I am participating in, one prerequisite was javascript object oriented & async programming, which I do not have experience in. However, having some experience in programming, I figured I would just learn as I go.

A practice activity (not a graded one, those I can not get help on) on blockchain hashing wants us to create an async hashing function using promises to hash data with SHA256. There are 2 main files: app.js, and block.js .

app.js (this was given to us, it is the main file we run):

```
/**
 * Importing the Block class
 */
//
const BlockClass = require('./block.js');

/**
 * Creating a block object
 */
const block = new BlockClass.Block("Test Block");

// Generating the block hash
block.generateHash().then((result) => {
    console.log(`Block Hash: ${result.hash}`);
    console.log(`Block: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
}).catch((error) => {console.log(error)});

/**
 * Step 3: Run the application in node.js
 * 
 */

// From the terminal: cd into Project folder
// From the terminal: Run node app.js to run the code
```

block.js ( the arrows indicate the part I added myself, everything else was given.

```
/**
 * Import crypto-js/SHA256 library
 */
const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

/**
 * Class with a constructor for block 
 */
class Block {

    constructor(data){
        this.id = 0;
        this.nonce = 144444;
        this.body = data;
        this.hash = "";
    }
    
    /**
     * Step 1. Implement `generateHash()`
     * method that return the `self` block with the hash.
     * 
     * Create a Promise that resolve with `self` after you create 
     * the hash of the object and assigned to the hash property `self.hash = ...`
     */
    // 
    generateHash() {
        // Use this to create a temporary reference of the class object
        let self = this;

> //Implement your code here
>         self.hash = SHA256(JSON.stringify(self.body));
>           const promise = new Promise(function(myResolve,myReject){
>           if(self.hash = SHA256(JSON.stringify(self.body))){
>           myResolve(self);
>           }else{
>            myReject(Error("It Broke")); 
>           }
>         
>         });
>       
>           promise.then(
>         function(result){this.hash = result.hash;},
>         function(error){console.log(error);}
>         );
>     }
}

// Exporting the class Block to be reuse in other files
module.exports.Block = Block;
```

Utilizing online resources, I do sort of understand promises, but not really- and definitely not how to apply them here. I was hoping I could get some help on this.

Comment: This task doesn't really make sense. [*crypto-js* does not appear to support asynchronous operation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/), so there's no point in using promises here. You might want to ask for clarification from your instructor.

Comment: learn as you go by [reading this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from head to tail. Review the excellent code examples. Reference your code, there is no need to use a promise if you are going to use it directly as you have in your code. The idea is to _return_ `promise` so it can be used by the caller.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Bergi - it appears the _exercise_ is to create and return a Promise to demonstrate how it works (apparently using a library that is in no way asynchronous).

Comment: Step 1.     Implement generateHash method in the Block class
Step 2 Use Promises to generate the hash asynchronously
Step 3 Run the application node app.js

Comment: Where do I even put the promise is the biggest thing for me. Also, why does the app.js file say generateHash.then if generateHash is not a promise.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Well, that makes it a very bad exercise though, as it does not help in understanding anything. Sure, you can implement `generateHash() { self.hash = SHA256(JSON.stringify(self.body)); return Promise.resolve(self); }`, but you've gained nothing.

Comment: @SaveerJain "*Use Promises to generate the hash asynchronously*" does not make sense. [Promises do not make anything asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js). They're a tool to deal with things that already are asynchronous.

Comment: would you mind explaining what return Promise.resolve(self) does

Comment: @SaveerJain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Best you might be able to achieve is using [`crypto.subtle.digest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) which *is* natively asynchronous, but I wonder if that goes against the idea of the exercise given it already does `const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');`. So yeah, ask your instructor what they want (or: what they want you to learn).

Comment: @Bergi - I completely agree. Contrived examples used for academic purposes are usually silly and do more harm than good.