# React running useEffect hook before rendering the page

Tags: reactjs, promise

I am making a Connect 4 Game with AI. Deciding the next move for the AI is an expensive calculation and so I want to handle it asynchronously. Currently when the human player places a counter the expensive calculation is run and then both counters appear on the game board. Instead I would like the human counter to appear, then the calculation be run, then the computer counter to appear. I have used the useEffect() hook to run the expensive calculation only when the game_board is updated however this has not fixed the problem. I feel like I have tried everything; moving all the state variables into a single useState() hook, using the flushSync() function to update the game_grid and prevent batching and adjusting the order of everything.

```
  const [game_grid, setGrid] = useState(createGrid(ROWS,COLS))
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(new Tree(new GameNode(null, 5), 2))
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false)


 useEffect(() => {
    if (pending) {
      opponentMove(game_grid, tree).then(([new_grid, new_tree]) => {
        setTree(new_tree)
        setGrid(new_grid)
        setPending(false)
      }) 
    }
 }, [game_grid])

function handlePlay(i: number) {
    let [new_grid, new_tree]= playTurns(i);
    setTree(new_tree);
    setPending(true);
    setGrid(new_grid);
  }
```

If I remove the useEffect statement, the human player's counter is placed instantly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Build Tool: Vite

Comment: If `tree` is the state that counters are held in, your code looks like it should work. `handlePlay` will call `setTree`, and then later, after a re-render has been painted to the screen, the effect hook should run and perform the opponent's turn. Maybe it's a CSS issue (eg, fade-in)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think it is a CSS issue because even if the return JSX directly modifies the HTML, the problem persists. game_grid holds the counter information.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think more of a MCVE is needed to debug the issue. Think you could edit a live Stack Snippet into the question to demonstrate (ideally - or if not, a codesandbox link or something)?

Comment: You shouldn't need a `useEffect` for this - calling it directly from `handlePlay` should work. Please show us how you implemented `opponentMove` - what exactly is asynchronous about it and how does it return a promise?

Comment: If `opponentMove` performs expensive operations before doing anything asynchronous, the effect callback is needed, I think - it'll only yield control flow back to React to render once it starts doing something async (and ends sync code)

Comment: @Bergi It seems your suspicions are correct. The computations in the promise return are blocking the render. If I replace the expensive computations with a `setTimeout` promise the code works as intended placing the human counter then the computer one after the set time. I am not really sure how to proceed though there doesn't seem to be any easy solution, except perhaps converting all functions called by `opponentMove` to return promises.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd think that React runs the effect synchronously within its rendering loop, so the browser still won't render/paint the updates it has already done.

Comment: @StevenL You only need to *start* the `opponentMove` implementation with a small timeout. And yes, [the executor function of a promise is blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js)