# Make a fast asynchronous lookup function with await Promise.all

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to implement a quick search function. a for loop is too slow. a for loop with break is better, but the speed depends heavily on where the object with the value you are looking for is in an array. a for loop with break is still synchronous. I would therefore like to search in all objects in parallel and as soon as the search value was found in one object, the search in all objects should be canceled and the value found returned.
here is my experiment:

```
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    
  let obj = {
    id: 0,  
    width: 10,
    height: 3,
    lengt: 20,
    diameter: null,
    data: null,
  }
    
  if(i == 657) obj.id = 5;   
  arr.push(obj);
}

async function test(){
        
  let results = await Promise.all(
    arr.map(async (obj) => {
        
     let res = obj.id;
     let index = arr.indexOf(obj);

     return {res, index}   

     //Ok now i look up parallel but i get an array with values ​​from each object back.
     //I just want the result found with the index of the object back and break all look ups

    })
  );            

  return results;  //I want only the match back, not all 
}

async function result(){
let res = await test();
        
console.log(res);
}       

result();
```

Does anyone have a good idea? I just want the value greater than zero and the index of the object in the array with the value

Comment: You pretty much cannot do this in JavaScript. A computer has only so many processor cores, after all, and on top of that JavaScript is not multi-threaded.

Comment: Have you determined speed is an actual issue? What are you **actually** searching? How is the data created and/or retrieved? Should you have some form of indexing if speed is **really** this much of a concern?

Comment: I compare coordinate points in threejs with an area grid. await Promis.all starts all searches at the same time. I use this in other places to load data in parallel. I haven't used it for search yet, but it sounds logical to me since it's an asynchronous function where everything is started at the same time

Comment: Nothing would work for me without multithreading. my search functions are in sidethreads. I just notice that the threads with the synchronous search function need significantly longer until they communicate back to the main thread. the main thread runs undisturbed because i keep it free from loading processes

Comment: "*await Promis.all starts all searches at the same time*" - no, it absolutely doesn't. [Promises do not make anything parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/proper-way-to-write-nonbloking-function-in-node-js). There are no threads here. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Store the elements in a better data structure, e.g. a hash map or a sorted list.